# Typescript Cannot find module 'meteor/easy:search'

Tags: angular, typescript, meteor, module, meteor-easy-search

My goal is to use ElasticSearch inside the meteor-angular2.0 example by Urigo (see link below).

For this I try to implement using [`easysearch:elasticsearch`](https://atmospherejs.com/easysearch/elasticsearch#) package in my existing project which is based on https://github.com/Urigo/meteor-angular2.0-socially .

After I used `meteor add easysearch:elasticsearch` I receive always the `Cannot find module error`if I try to implement it (serverside/clientside/both - doesnt matter).
Here my code of implementation in the `both/collections/cases.collections.ts` file:

```
import { MongoObservable } from "meteor-rxjs";
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Index } from 'meteor/easy:search' // gives error
import { ElasticSearchEngine } from 'meteor/easysearch:elasticsearch' //gives error

import { Case } from "../models/case.model";

export const Cases = new MongoObservable.Collection<Case>("cases");

// const CasesIndex = new Index({
//   collection: Cases,
//   fields: ['name', 'description'],
//   engine: new ElasticSearchEngine({
//     body: () => { } // modify the body that's sent when searching
//   })

function loggedIn() {
  return !!Meteor.user();
}

Cases.allow({
  insert: loggedIn,
  update: loggedIn,
  remove: loggedIn
});
```

My `.meteor/packages` file has following content:

```
# Meteor packages used by this project, one per line.
# Check this file (and the other files in this directory) into your repository.
#
# 'meteor add' and 'meteor remove' will edit this file for you,
# but you can also edit it by hand.

meteor-base@1.0.4             # Packages every Meteor app needs to have
mobile-experience@1.0.4       # Packages for a great mobile UX
mongo@1.1.14                   # The database Meteor supports right now
reactive-var@1.0.11            # Reactive variable for tracker
tracker@1.1.1                 # Meteor's client-side reactive programming library

standard-minifier-css@1.3.2   # CSS minifier run for production mode
standard-minifier-js@1.2.1    # JS minifier run for production mode
es5-shim@4.6.15                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers.

angular2-compilers
practicalmeteor:mocha
xolvio:cleaner
hwillson:stub-collections
dispatch:mocha-phantomjs
shell-server@0.2.1
accounts-password
anti:fake
tmeasday:publish-counts
check
email
jalik:ufs
jalik:ufs-gridfs
mickaelfm:vermongo
easysearch:elasticsearch
easysearch:core
easy:search
```

Additionally (if it helps) here my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "a angular2 elasticsearch site",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run",
    "start:prod": "meteor run --production",
    "build": "meteor build ./build/",
    "clear": "meteor reset",
    "meteor:update": "meteor update --all-packages",
    "test": "meteor test --driver-package practicalmeteor:mocha",
    "test:ci": "meteor test --once --driver-package dispatch:mocha-phantomjs"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "3.5.2",
    "@types/meteor": "^1.4.1",
    "@types/mocha": "2.2.41",
    "chai": "3.5.0",
    "chai-spies": "0.7.1",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "0.2.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/http": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/router": "^4.4.3",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.22",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.8.1",
    "angular2-file-drop": "^0.2.0",
    "angular2-google-maps": "0.17.0",
    "angular2-meteor": "0.7.1",
    "angular2-meteor-accounts-ui": "1.0.0",
    "angular2-meteor-polyfills": "0.2.0",
    "angular2-meteor-tests-polyfills": "0.0.2",
    "babel-runtime": "6.23.0",
    "bcrypt": "=1.0.2",
    "gm": "^1.23.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "0.2.11",
    "meteor-rxjs": "0.4.7",
    "meteor-typings": "1.3.1",
    "ng2-drag-drop": "^2.0.1",
    "ng2-pagination": "^2.0.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "ng2-cytoscape": "0.4.0",
    "rxjs": "5.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.11"
  }
}
```

Still the same errors - I have added the package with `meteor add easy:search` and rebuild the whole app via `npm run start`.

Additionally I shifted the imports to the server side - just to be sure that there are no problems  but I still get the the error in the Atom editor and the chrome console.

Could it be that that I have some problems because I'm not using Blaze components?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to install [`easy:search`](https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-easy-search/) package itself.

```
cd /path/to/project
meteor add easy:search
```

Comment: Still the same errors - I have added the package with meteor add easy:search and rebuild the whole app via npm run start.

Comment: Would it help if I add the 'npm-debug-log' additionally?

Comment: @SaschaN. It could.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - anything was installed very well but the compiler, the editor (Atom with Typescript package) and the console gave me an error because of the missing typings.

Just added the following bad minimal type definitions to `typings.d.ts` to connect successfully to the running elasticsearch server.

```
declare module 'meteor/easysearch:core' {
  import { Mongo } from "meteor/mongo";

  interface config {
    collection: any,
    fields: string[],
    engine: any
  }

  class Index {
    constructor(config: config);
    search(searchDefinition: string, options?: object): Mongo.Cursor<any>;
  }
}


declare module 'meteor/easysearch:elasticsearch' {
  interface params {
    body: any
  }

  class ElasticSearchEngine {
    constructor(obj: params);
  }
}
```